# Neo4j and cypher: how to match/create specific parts of a path?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have pre-existing nodes `a` and `b`, and want to create a path

```
(a) <-[:FROM]- (c:Comp) -[:TO]-> (b)
```

Unless it already exists. `create unique` doesn't quite work here, because if we already have

```
(a) <-[:FROM]- (d:Comp) -[:TO]-> (e)
```

Then `d` will get reused as `c`, and only the relationship `(c) -[:TO]-> (b)` will get created. I want to create a new `:Comp` node in this case.

Whether or not the `:Comp` node was just created, I subsequently want to `create unique` a relationship from it.

I've come up with two possible solutions that I don't particularly like:

I think I could do it with optional relationships, something like

```
match (a) <-[r1?:FROM]- (c:Comp) -[r2?:TO]-> (b)
where r1 is null or r2 is null
create (a) <-[:FROM]- (d:Comp) -[:TO]-> (b)
```

But I'm not sure how I'd create the extra relationship if the `:Comp` node already exists.

Another option is to have properties on `c` uniquely identifying `a` and `b`, along the lines of

```
(a) <-[:FROM]- (c:Comp { from: a.uuid, to: b.uuid }) -[:TO]-> (b)
```

So that `create unique` won't start with a partial match. But having redundant data lying around is a smell.

Answer (score 1):

I created what I think is your model in a console: http://console.neo4j.org/?id=l6q3q0

Perhaps try this:

```
START a=node:node_auto_index(name='a'), b=node:node_auto_index(name='b')
WHERE NOT (a<-[:FROM]-(:Comp)-[:TO]->b)
CREATE a<-[:FROM]-(c:Comp), c-[:TO]->b
```

Comment: That's an accurate model, your suggestion is nicer than what I did with optional relationships, so thanks.

But I probably wasn't very clear: after creating-or-finding c, I need a new relationship, `CREATE UNIQUE c-[:SUGGESTED_BY]->(x:Algo)`. Here I can do that if I've just created c, by adding that line to your code, but I'm not sure how I'd do it if c already existed.

Comment: Are you using Neo 1.9 or 2.0?  If using 2.0 you might be able to use a CASE WHEN expression.  Otherwise it might be easier to use two different queries.  The first would ensure it exists, the second would create the next relationship.

Comment: I'm using 2.0, but it looks like CASE can only have expressions in the WHEN parts, and can't be used with CREATE. (e.g. `CREATE CASE 3 WHEN 2 THEN (x:Two) ELSE (x:Three) END` apparently thinks that CASE is what's being created, and throws a syntax error on the first 3.) I might have to go with two queries. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried yet, but it looks like `MERGE` can do this as of 2.0.0-rc1. http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-merge.html

I'll want something like

```
MERGE (a) <-[:FROM]- (c:Comp) -[:TO]-> (b)
CREATE UNIQUE (c) -[:SUGGESTED_BY]-> (x:Algo)
```